# jQuery scripts different order depending on first load or second refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onload

I have a script that adds html code dynamically using jQuery (loops through a text file and loads images). After that, I apply dynamic CSS style and onclick events to the previously loaded images.

When I load the page for the first time it works fine. But when I refresh (normal F5) the scripts execute in reverse order (first changes CSS and events, then adds html code), so obviously the images don't have the CSS and events I need.

I know they execute in reverse order because I've "debugged" using alerts. And they appear in reverse order on first load than on second refresh.

I suspect it's a timing issue regarding load events (onload, DOMload, etc..).

I'm asking here because all I could find were post about people having the opposite problem. Their code not working on first load, but working fine after refresh. I haven't found a single post about my problem.

This is my index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Magnum</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<!-- Favicons
    ================================================== -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">

<!-- Stylesheet
    ================================================== -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nivo-lightbox/nivo-lightbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nivo-lightbox/default.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>


<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">



<!-- Navigation -->
<div id="nav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </button>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-main-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
          <li class="hidden"> <a href="#page-top"></a> </li>
          <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a> </li>
          <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a> </li>
          <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<!-- Portfolio Section -->

<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-title text-center center">
      <h2>Portfolio</h2>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="categories">
      <ul class="cat">
        <li>
          <ol class="type">
            <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".graphic">Graphic Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".illustration">Illustration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".photography">Photography</a></li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="portfolio-items" id="portfoli">
   
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 graphic">
          <div class="portfolio-item">
            <div class="hover-bg"> <a href="img/portfolio/01-large.jpg" title="Project Title" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1">
              <div class="hover-text">
                <h4>Project Title</h4>
              </div>
              <img src="img/portfolio/01-small.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Project Title"> </a> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 illustration">
          <div class="portfolio-item">
            <div class="hover-bg"> <a href="img/portfolio/02-large.jpg" title="Project Title" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1">
              <div class="hover-text">
                <h4>Project Title</h4>
              </div>
              <img src="img/portfolio/02-small.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Project Title"> </a> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/MostrarPortfoliIllustracio.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/SmoothScroll.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nivo-lightbox.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact_me.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the script that adds html dynamically from txt file (MostrarPortfoliIllustracio.js):

```js
$.get('portfoli.txt', function(data) {
  console.log("x.x");
  var lines = data.split('\n');
  var foto = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    alert("---> " + i);
    foto[i] = lines[i].split(";");
    document.getElementById("portfoli").innerHTML += '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ' + foto[i][0] + '">' +
      '<div class="portfolio-item">' +
      '<div class="hover-bg"> <a href="img/portfolio/' + foto[i][1] + '" title="' + foto[i][2] + '" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1">' +
      '<div class="hover-text">' +
      '<h4>' + foto[i][3] + '</h4>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<img src="img/portfolio/' + foto[i][4] + '" class="img-responsive" alt="Project Title"> </a> </div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';
  }
}, 'text');
```

This is the main.js script that modifies the  tags css and events:

```js
function main() {
  (function() {
    'use strict';

    $('a.page-scroll').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - 40
          }, 900);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });

    // affix the navbar after scroll below header
    $('#nav').affix({
      offset: {
        top: $('header').height()
      }
    });

    // Portfolio isotope filter
    $(window).load(function() {
      console.log("o.o");
      var $container = $('.portfolio-items');
      $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
          duration: 750,
          easing: 'linear',
          queue: false
        }
      });
      $('.cat a').click(function() {
        $('.cat .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
          filter: selector,
          animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
          }
        });
        return false;
      });

    });
    // Nivo Lightbox 
    $('.portfolio-item a').nivoLightbox({
      effect: 'slideDown',
      keyboardNav: true,
    });
  }());
}
main();
```

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous, so the timing of the alerts in the callback doesn't have anything to do with the order that the scripts are loaded. The difference between loading the first time and refreshing is probably related to caching.

Comment: wow @barmar, your answer was right on point. I switched $.get for $.ajax and set the async parameter to False. It works like a charm now. Thank you!

Comment: Synchronous AJAX is deprecated, you should not use it. You should design your code so that the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Anything that depends on the result of the AJAX call should be in the callback function.